# Simple Firebase notification not working on Android

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

So, I've been trying for hours to make notification works but without success.
My goal is to send a notification from the Firebase console and receive it on the phone. This means that I should only add the library to my application and configure a project on Firebase.

In my app I'm already using firebase for storage, analytics and ads without problem.

I've followed [the official tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) and also [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2tNlPjIe-A)

I've not added the service in the manifest because I don't need to do any particular message handling

This is my manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.domain.myapp">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    
        <application
            android:name=".App"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.myapp">
            <activity android:name="com.domain.myapp.MainActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    
            <provider
                android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
                android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
                android:exported="false"
                android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    
                android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                    android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
            </provider>
    
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
                android:value="myid"/>
        </application>
    
    </manifest>
```

root level build.gradle

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.20"
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
            def nav_version = "2.3.4"
            classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }
    
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Application level build file

```
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'kotlin-android'
        id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
        id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
        id 'kotlin-kapt'
        id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
    
    android {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                storeFile file('keystore')
                storePassword 'psw'
                keyAlias 'key0'
                keyPassword 'psw'
            }
        }
        compileSdkVersion 30
        buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.domain.myapp"
            minSdkVersion 22
            targetSdkVersion 30
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
    
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            def AD_UNIT_ID = "AD_UNIT_ID"
    
            debug {
                buildConfigField "String", AD_UNIT_ID, AD_UNIT_ID_TEST
            }
    
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                buildConfigField "String", AD_UNIT_ID, AD_UNIT_ID_PROD
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
    
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx:21.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:18.0.2'
        def nav_version = "2.3.4"
        implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
        implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
        implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version"
        implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha09"
    
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    
        implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0")
        implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:recyclerview-integration:4.11.0")
        kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
    
        implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:7.1.1'
    
        implementation 'com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.4.0'
    
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.8.0'
    
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    }
```

This is my App class:

```
    class App: Application() {
    
        override fun onCreate() {
            super.onCreate()
            MobileAds.initialize(this)
        }
    }
```

And this is my main activity:

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            setupAdViewInto(adContainer)
        }
    
        private fun setupAdViewInto(adContainer: LinearLayout, adSize: AdSize = SMART_BANNER) {
            val adView = AdView(this)
            adView.adSize = adSize
            adView.adUnitId = AD_UNIT_ID
            adContainer.addView(adView)
            adView.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
        }
    
    }
```

On the firebase console I see this:

[image]

Note: I've tried crating a new app from scratch and to do the same operation and that it's working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working, but I don't know how... I'm thinking is Android Studio's fault.

I've done these steps

- created a new project on firebase
- downloaded and imported the new google-services.json
- cleaned cache data and reinstalled the app on the emulator using the button Run 'app' from Android Studio
- the app is still showing stuff from the old firebase application, like it's using the old google-services.json
- deleted gradle's build folder from Android Studio
- reinstalled the app as before using the old configuration
- notifications are now working
- WTF!??

I'm thinking that the problem was due to gralde/android studio.

I've lost like 5 hours on this... I love programming :) :)